# Get a string with HTML tags inside a larger string with ColdFusion regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion-9

I'm new to regular expressions and could use some help.

I am attempting to use a ColdFusion `REReplace` to scrape data and get my desired content.

This is what I have so far:

```
<cfoutput>
#REReplace("Remove this please <p>Make this Display Please</p> Remove this please", "", "", "All")#
</cfoutput>
```

What regular expression could take that string and return only "Make this Display Please"?

Comment: Most probably `...".*<p>(.*?)</p>.*", "\1", "All")`.

Comment: That worked. Thank You very much. I don't understand all the syntax yet and I'm trying to learn .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a subtext from a longer string, you need to match everything up to what you need, capture what you need with a capturing group `(...)`, and then match the rest of the string up to the end. The replacement is `\1` back-reference that references the text captured by the capturing group.

So, use

```
#REReplace("Remove this please <p>Make this Display Please</p> Remove this please", ".*<p>(.*?)</p>.*", "\1", "All")#
```

The regex matches:

- `.*` - matches any character but a newline from the beginning up to the last `</p>`
- `<p>` - the literal `<p>`
- `(.*?)` - 0 or more characters other than newline symbol as few as possible (it means up to the closest `</p>` here)
- `</p>` - matches literal `</p>`
- `.*` - matches the rest of text to the end (no newlines).

To match newlines, use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you, and upvoting if you found it helpful.